# Find the volume of the region bounded by a sphere and a paraboloid using cylindrical and spherical coordinates.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The sphere is $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ and the paraboloid is $x^2 + y^2 = 3z$

I've already done for the cylindrical coordinates and got:

$$\int^{2\pi}_0\int_0^1\int_{\frac{r^2}{3}}^\sqrt{4-r^2}rdzdrd\theta = \frac{\pi(31-12\sqrt{3})}{6}$$

But I'm having troubles when building the integral for spherical coordinates. So far I've found the bounds of integration for $d\rho$ and $d\theta$.

$$\int^{2\pi}_0\int\int_0^2\rho ^2\sin\phi \,\,\,d\rho d\phi d\theta$$

What about the bounds for $d\phi$? Done a small search and had to solve $3\rho\cos\phi = \rho^2\sin^2\theta$, but this is the point where I'm stuck. Is this right? If yes, how to solve this?

Comment: The paraboloid has to be something more than just $x^2+y^2+3z$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos unfortunately, that's all the author has given.

Comment: Then your question makes no sense.

Comment: Did you mean $x^2+y^2 = 3z$? If I see the lower bound of $z$ in your cylindrical coordinates working, it seems the paraboloid is $x^2+y^2 = 3z$. But upper bound of $r$ is wrong. How did you get $r = 1$ as upper bound?

Comment: @MathLover thanks for noticing my mistake. I found $r = 1$ by substituion and then bhaskara. But doing it again it seems $r = 3$, thanks again.

Comment: OK so you can easily fix cylindrical coordinates now. For spherical coordinates, please note that for $\phi \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$, you are bound by the sphere. So that is straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates, the volume is

$$\int^{2\pi}_0 \int_0^{\sqrt3} \int^{-\frac{r^2}{3}}_{-\sqrt{4-r^2}} r\>dr d\theta 
= \frac{19\pi}6$$

and, in spherical coordinates

$$\int^{2\pi}_0 \int_{\pi/2}^{2\pi/3} \int_0^{-\frac{3\cos\phi}{\sin^2\phi}}
\rho ^2\sin\phi \,d\rho d\phi d\theta
+\int^{2\pi}_0 \int^{\pi}_{2\pi/3} \int_0^{2}
\rho ^2\sin\phi \,d\rho d\phi d\theta = \frac{19\pi}6$$

Comment: Could you say how to find the bounds for spherical?

Comment: @ShinYousoro - you need to integrate over two ranges, one over the paraboloid within $\phi \in (\pi/2, 2\pi/3) $ and the other over the sphere within $\phi \in (2\pi/3,\pi)$

Answer (score 1):

At the intersection of paraboloid and sphere,

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4, x^2+y^2 = 3z \implies z^2 + 3z - 4 = 0$.

i.e, $z = 1, x^2+y^2 = 3$.

So in cylindrical coordinates, $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt3$.

**Now in spherical coordinates,**

$x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi,y = \rho \sin\theta \sin\phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$

At the intersection of paraboloid and sphere,

$\rho = 2, z = \rho \cos\phi = 1,  \implies \cos\phi = \frac{1}{2}$

So for $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$, the region is bound by the sphere and for $\frac{\pi}{3} \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, the region is bound by the paraboloid.

$3z = x^2 + y^2 \implies 3 \rho \cos\phi = \rho^2 \sin^2\phi$

$\rho = 3 \cos\phi \csc^2\phi$

So bounds for the second integral are,

$\frac{\pi}{3} \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}, 0 \leq \rho \leq 3 \cos\phi \csc^2\phi $